# how to copy default radiobuttonstyle

Tags: android, radio-button, styles

I am creating radio buttons programmatically with the following code:

```
new RadioButton(getActivity());
```

However, these radio buttons created that way do not look like as the default radio button created from an xml file.

How can I copy the default radio button style?

[image]

I also tried the following format but it still didn't work.

```
new RadioButton(getActivity(), null, com.android.internal.R.attr.radioButtonStyle);
```

I got following error:

> Error:(147, 81) error: package com.android.internal.R does not exist Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `AppCompatActivity`, you should use [AppCompatRadioButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.html) to programmatically create a RadioButton with the default styling of AppCompat.